# Display image to a view from controller with jquery ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core

On a button click, I want to call a Controller method in which I create a PNG image dynamically. I want to then send that image to the view and display it for the user to see. I can't quite figure out how to properly do this, or what I'm exactly doing wrong. My code is as follows:

**View**

```
<div style="height:350px; margin:10px;">
    <img id="rsDiagram" src="" alt="RS Diagram" class="partDiagram">
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult RSView(string orderNumber)
    {
        // I create the png and save it to wwwroot/images/
        string outfile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "RSView.png"));

        string fileToSend = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outfile));

        return Json(fileToSend);
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
//This is called on a button click
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/RSView",
    data: { "orderNumber": $("#shopOrderNumber").val() },
    success: function (response) {
        rs.style.display = "block";
        $("rsDiagram").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + response + '"');
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: For starters, the `img` tag should be addressed via $("#rsDiagram") - the `#` is missing.

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Comment: Yes the problem was resolved. Thank you for pointing out to cleaning up the success command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your code is almost alright only little problem founded how you are binding the response on your image tag. Just replace the below line with your older one.

```
  $("#rsDiagram").attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + response);
```

> ***Note:***  I have tried to keep all of your existing code.

So the full solution would be looks like

***Controller:***
Same as yours

```
public ActionResult RSView()
        {
            // I create the png and save it to wwwroot/images/
            string outfile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "RSView.png"));

            string fileToSend = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outfile));

            return Json(fileToSend);
        }
```

***View:***

Also same, I just added a button so that anyone can test with this solution

```
<div style="height:350px; margin:10px;">
    <img id="rsDiagram" src=""  class="partDiagram">
</div>
<!-- Button for calling ajax request -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Load Images
</button>
```

***Javascript:***

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function (e) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Home/RSView",
                    //data: { "orderNumber": $("#shopOrderNumber").val() },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#rsDiagram").attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + response);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

> ***Note:*** Here in `ajax` request I have commented your parameter `{ "orderNumber": $("#shopOrderNumber").val()` as I am calling the
> `controller` for the predefined image so that I didn't sent any parameter. Hope you get me here.

***Output:***
[image]

Hope it would resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this worked and helps a lot. I tried piecing different sources together and this answer helps put it all together.

Comment: Glad that it helps, you were also close enough, but problem is when some contributor answers they doesn't consider the existing scenario which is important to resolve the problem. I always focus on the current context and reproduce the issue so that you doesn't confused. I always try to answer in a way, so that just copy and paste make it work without any furher modification. Thanks